# List of doubled even numbers. Elixir

Tags: list, recursion, elixir

I'm trying to implement a function called `even/2` that takes a list of numbers and returns an equivalent list but one where all even numbers have been doubled. I'm supposed to use the
function `rem(n, k)` which returns the reminder when dividing `n` with `k`.

I understand `/2` means takes two arguments.

I tried to solve it by using an anonymous function to check the remainders of each element in the list if it's even, but I don't know how to place it in new list then output it.

Comment: i guess this is homework - and the teacher has asked for tail-recursion.  Read up about it here: https://www.culttt.com/2016/06/06/understanding-recursion-tail-call-optimisation-elixir/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE/REWRITE**: Use this tail recursion

```
defmodule Main do 

  def doubleEven( [], output ) do # case of input empty list
    Enum.reverse output
  end

  def doubleEven( [head | tail], output ) do # any other length list
    if rem(head, 2) == 0 do 
      doubleEven(tail, [head*2 | output]) 
    else
      doubleEven(tail, [head | output]) 
    end
  end

end
```

Which get called using:

```
Main.doubleEven( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [] )
```

and outputs

```
[1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 12, 7, 16, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you but i think the output will be only even numbers , and it will takes 2 argument

Comment: It's not the hard to modify to make it do what you want.  However I'll update my answer to spell it out.

Comment: Thank you, i understand everything now

Comment: @Maher.Riyadh Thanks are nice - perhaps you could upvote and accept mine as answer .

Comment: @Maher.Riyadh https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+accept+answer

Answer (score 3):

One can use `rem/2` in guards:

```
Enum.map(input, fn
  even when rem(even, 2) == 0 -> even * 2
  odd -> odd
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, a simple way to do this with one argument:

```elixir
defmodule Double do
  def double([]), do: []
  def double([head | tail]) when rem(head, 2) == 0, do: [head * 2 | double(tail)]
  def double([head | tail]), do: [head | double(tail)]
end
```

This uses pattern matching of the argument to assign the first element of the list to the `head` variable.

`when rem(head, 2) == 0` is a guard that means this function clause will only get executed when it is true (the first item of the list is even, in this case).

We then return a new list consisting of the possibly doubled value, and use recursion to compute the rest of the list.

The above method builds up the result in the call stack. I suspect the reason you are asked to use two arguments is to take advantage of [tail-call optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization), which means even though a recursive call it made, no extra stack frames are used. Because we don't have a call stack in which to build the result, we add an extra `output` argument and build it there:

```elixir
defmodule Double do
  def double([], output), do: Enum.reverse(output)
  def double([head | tail], output) when rem(head, 2) == 0, do: double(tail, [head * 2 | output])
  def double([head | tail], output), do: double(tail, [head | output])
end
```

Here we write a function that takes an `input` and an `output` list.
The function calls itself until the `input` has been exhausted (is the empty list `[]`), and builds up the answer in the `output` list, which it eventually returns. In each call, we prepend the current item to the output list.

```elixir
iex> Double.double([1,2,3,4], [])
[1, 4, 3, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go best implementation you can find :P

```
def double_even([]) do [] end
def double_even([h|t]) do
  case rem(h,2) do
    0 ->
      [h*2|double_even(t)]
    _ ->
      [h|double_even(t)]
  end
end
```

Comment: The function even should take two argument , you solved it with one argument

Comment: No, it shouldn't :3

Comment: yes, but I mean the function could be implemented with only one argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
  def even([], acc), do: Enum.reverse(acc)
  def even([h|t], acc) when rem(h,2) == 0, do: even(t, [2*h|acc])
  def even([h|t], acc), do: even(t, [h|acc])
```